# is it possible to split a react-bootstrap component to 2 components?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I`m working with react-redux, is it possible to split a react-bootstrap component to 2 components (parent-child)?
for example:

//parent Tabs_component

```
return (
    <Tabs defaultActiveKey={1}>
        <Tab_component />
    </Tabs>
)
```

// child Tab_component

```
   return (
        <div>
            <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1">Tab 1 content</Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2">Tab 2 content</Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3">Tab 3 content</Tab>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: In order to do what? What is the functionality you want to have here?

Comment: in order to better separate logic and style, and to make the components more reusable.